# The model of a free particle in a box as an approximation for the translational motion of a particle in a gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, kinetic-theory, gas, partition-function

According to the book [Introduction to Physical Gas Dynamics](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1965itpg.book.....V/abstract) (starting from page 120), the translational motion of a particle in a gas in thermal equilibrium may be approximated by a free particle in a rigid box. By solving the Schrödinger for this system one may show that the resultant translational partition function is given by
$$Q_{\text{tr}}(T,V)=V\left(\frac{2\pi mk_BT}{h^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\text{ ,}$$
where $T$ is the temperature, $V$ is the volume of the box, $m$ is the mass of the particle, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann's constant and $h$ is the Planck's constant.

My question is how should this rigid box be interpreted? Is it a box with the dimensions of the mean free path of the particle, such that it represents the space whose boundary the particle can't cross due to collisions with other particles?

Comment: In obtaining the above partition funciton, did they use the high temperature limit?

Comment: What do you mean by approximating the translational motion by free particles in a box? What feature of the translational motion are you interested in?

Comment: @ytlu They didn't consider a high temperature limit. They simply approximated the sum involved in the definition of the partition function by an integral which is valid for a not too low temperature.

Comment: @GiorgioP I'm solely interested in the fact that the authors considered a particle constrained to a rigid box instead of being subjected to collisions with other particles as happens in reality. And if the model of a rigid box is used, should this box be one which has the dimensions of the mean free path of the particle, or other dimensions? If it happens to be the first case, then, I would in some way understand the approximation, though, without certainty.

Comment: Have you heard of the [thermal de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength)?